# Dash - gauge charts size

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dashboard, plotly-python

I'm new to Dash and need a little help

I need to decrease the height of my gauge charts, but when I try it I don't see the full figures (some numbers and the title are not visible):[image]

The code that is responsible for generating these figures is the following:

```
def get_language_statistics_figure(value, text):
    if text == "Impact of unknown types URLs":
        gauge = {'axis': {'range': [0, 1]}, 'bar': {'color': "red"}}
    else:
        gauge = {'axis': {'range': [0, 1]}}
    
    # Indicators for precision and impact
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(
    go.Indicator(
    mode = "gauge+number",
    value = value,
    title = {'text': text},
    domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},
    gauge = gauge
)
)
    fig.update_layout(margin=dict(t=0, b=0, r=0, l=0, pad=0), height=250, width=500)
    return fig
```

I hope you can help me.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you share code that can be run as is and reproduces the problem? I've tested it based on your example and the labels aren't being cut off on my end. The problem could be in some other part of your layout that you haven't shared (the height of a parent element of the indicator for example).

Comment: It was exactly the height of the parent element.